# oci_connect() won't use object properties as arguments

Tags: php, database, oracle

Parameters(private strings):

```
    $this->username = 'app';
    $this->password = 'passwd';
    $this->service = '//local/DEV';
```

Doesn't work:

```
    $conn = oci_connect($this->username,$this->password,$this->service);
```

Does work:

```
    $conn = oci_connect('app','passwd','//local/DEV');
```

Why doesn't oci_connect like the object properties as arguments?  I get an invalid login error when using the object properties, but success when I use strings.  All of this code is in the __construct() of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You have `//localhost/DEV` in the object but `//local/DEV` in the strings, so they aren't the same service.

Comment: Fixed the typo, same problem exists.

Comment: OK, you're going to need more detail like using `var_dump` on each of `$this->username`, `$this->password` and `$this->service` to make sure they really are what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PDO to connect?  I know they have deprecated the mysql_ extension not sure on oracle.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php

snippet with your informatiion:

```
$dbc = new PDO('oci:dbname=local/DEV;charset=CL8MSWIN1251', 'app', 'passwd');
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but it doesn't answer my question.  At this point in the project, I can't justify rebuilding the DB handling.

Comment: Right on didn't know how far in it you were, just a suggestion. :)